# PHP didnt echo the data send by ajax

Tags: php, jquery

do you know whats wrong with my code? I thought it would work.
I just want to echo the data from input to div without refreshing website.
Ajax sent data, but php didnt show them and i really dont understand why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $(document).on("submit", ".form", function()
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://dev.nostools.cz/',
                    data: $('.form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                      //alert('form was submitted');
                    }
                  });
            })
        });

    </script>
    <div style="width: 250px; height: 100px;">
        <div id="show" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid black;">
        <?php

            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                echo $_POST['console']; //echo data or do something here
            }

        ?>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 20%;">
            <form class="form" method="post">
                <input id="console" style="padding: 0; width: 67%;" type="text" name="console" />
                <input style="padding: 0; width: 31%;" type="submit" name="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't send a POST to another domain, you're probably hitting CORS errors. Check your developer console.

Comment: Are you trying to send the POST request to the same page and assume it will appear instantly?

Comment: Yes i want to show data insantly

Comment: The AJAX request result does not automatically merge into the page... You need to process the response with code in the success callback!

Answer (score 0):

As php is server side scripting language php script runs only on server side ...
Here you are trying to handle/run php script on client side which is not correct way.. to show data make following changes in your success function.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://dev.nostools.cz/',
                data: $('.form').serialize(),
                ***success: function (data) {***
                  $("#show").html($("#console").val());
                }
              });


<?php
    $_POST['console'];
    //process your data.
    echo $processed_data;
?>
```

Comment: So if i want to show modified data by php back to page and appear what i have to do?

Comment: what you have to show...? value of console from input type

Comment: i want to send that data from input to php then "edit them in php" and show them but without refreshing page if you understand me